# How to design Splash Screen Animated Attractive Landing Screen Animation in xamarin forms. cross platform

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, splash-screen, launchimage

I need splash screen animation before entering the main page in android and iOS. but I unable to find this type of animation. tell me anyone knows this means, kindly give me an idea. I  attach the below reference. its in developed in native android. how to develop this process in xamarin forms cross-platform(android & iOS).

Reference  : https://demonuts.com/splash-screen-animation/

Comment: no. i did not know how to integrate this type of animation.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the animation on a **ContentPage** and set it as MainPage firstly to let it looks like an illusory  splash screen. Then you can change the MainPage use Timer `Task.Delay(1000);`

And you can use the library **[Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/)** from Nuget. Lottie is a library, designed for iOS, Android that allows you run animations.  These animations are defined in a JSON file, containing all the details of colors, shapes, transforms and more.

#### Usage

First install the following Nuget package to your native and share projects.

```
Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie
```

In your native projects, after the Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init line, add the following, into each project.(`AppDelegate.cs` in iOS and `MainActivity.cs` in Android)

```
AnimationViewRenderer.Init();
```

In order to show an animation, you first need the after effects JSON file. Put this in your Assets (Android) or Resources (iOS) folder.

```
<forms:AnimationView x:Name="AnimationView"
                         Animation="LottieLogo1.json"
                         Loop="True"
                         AutoPlay="True"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

There is a [sample](https://github.com/adamped/LottieAnimationSample) maybe can help you.